# How to show that a function is in O($h^m$)

Tags: limits

i try to find the biggest m that 
    $$f(h) = \frac{e^h-e^{-h}}{2h}-1$$
is $\in O(h^m)$ ($h \to 0, h > 0$)

I thought i have to use the definition.

So i wrote this:
$$    limsup_{h \to 0} \left | \frac{\frac{e^h-e^-h}{2h}-1}{h^m} \right | = limsup_{h \to 0} \left | \frac{e^h-e^{-h}-2h}{h^m \cdot 2h} \right |$$

but now, i dont know how to estimate further. This term should be $< \infty$.

Can you help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
f(h):&=&\frac{e^h-e^{-h}}{2h}-1\\
&=&\frac{1}{2h}\left[\left(1+h+\frac{h^2}{2}+\frac{h^3}{3!}+\frac{h^4}{4!}+\ldots\right)-\left(1-h+\frac{h^2}{2}-\frac{h^3}{3!}+\frac{h^4}{4!}+\ldots\right)\right]-1\\
&=&\frac{1}{2h}\left(2h+\frac{2h^3}{3!}+\frac{2h^5}{5!}+\ldots\right)-1\\
&=&\frac{h^2}{3!}+\frac{h^4}{5!}+\ldots=h^2\left(\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{h^2}{5!}+\ldots\right)=:h^2g(h).
\end{eqnarray}
Since 
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}g(h)=\frac16, 
$$
we have $f(h)=O(h^2)$ as $h \to 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much, awesome=)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Your function is $$\frac{\sinh h}{h}-1, $$ and the hyperbolic sine has the following series expansion $$\sinh h=h+\frac{h^3}{3!}+\frac{h^5}{5!}+ \dots $$